# PHP and AJAX Updating notifications in real time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Currently having some trouble with an AJAX call. It is meant to display notifications in real time, with reference to an external php file. When I tested the php inside index.php it worked fine, but for some reason it doesn't work when I try to call the code via ajax. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Solved by adding session_start(); at top of file, and also by using .class instead of #id in ajax call.

In notif_follow.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';

$user_notif = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];

$stmt = $user_notif->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$user_id));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $user_notif->runQuery("SELECT * FROM notif_follow WHERE receive_id=:rid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(array(":rid"=>$user_id));
$notifs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$notification = '';

if($notifs !== false)
 {
  foreach($notifs as $notif)
  {
   $notification .= '
   <li>
     <div class="notifbox">
     <strong>'.$notif['send_name'].'</strong><p> is now following you.</p>
     <button class="button">Follow</button><button class="button">View Channel</button>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $notification .= '<li><a href="#" class="text-bold text-italic">No Notifications Found</a></li>';
 }

header('Content-type: application/json');
$notif_array = array('notification'=>$notification);
echo json_encode($notif_array);
?>
```

Ajax call in index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer;

timer = setInterval(function() {

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('notif_follow.php', function(data) {
          $('#notifbox').html(data.notification);
        });
      });

}, 1 * 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the session ID around like that. Starting a session sets a cookie, and sending an AJAX request will send the cookie along, just like clicking a link or sending a form does. Just access `$_SESSION['userID']` at the top of the script you're requesting, and it will work fine. As an aside I'll recommend not to return JSON wrapping HTML, especially not if all you're passing is a single String. Instead, pass the array of usernames, then compose the HTML in the client. This way you can reuse your PHP api for an app without having to rewrite everything.

Comment: For some reason when I put $user_id = $_SESSION['userID']; at the top I get the error: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: You need to put `session_start();` at the top.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I also removed the id echo from the ajax call. It's still not updating for some reason.

Comment: Turns out it was the id of the div not being recognized. Currently using bootstrap, and the class is over-riding the id#. Thanks for your help.